# Does calling await on a no task creation method do anything Asynchronous?

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider the following:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync()
{
  // no creation of a task in these statements
  statement2;
  statement3;
  statement4;
  return Task.FromResult( true );
}

public async Task MyMethod()
{
  statement1;
  await DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
  statement5;
}
```

Is there any asynchronous behaviour to be run when awaiting `DoSomethingAsync`?

Comment: What do you call "asynchronous behavior"? The answer is probably "No", but it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: does statement5 to be executed in a thread differs from the one that executes statment1

Comment: No, same thread. But even if the method is asynchronous it does not mean that it would be executed in a different  thread. Asynchrony and parallelism are different matters. [You may want to check this article.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/)

Comment: I think he is trying to ask, what might be the benefit of using async if you are going to await for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any asynchronous behaviour to be run when awaiting `DoSomethingAsync`?

No, there isn't. When `DoSomthingAsync` is called, it is executed whole and returned `Task` is already finished. So when await tries to wire-up the callback logic, it finds out the task is already finished and just continues execution without bothering with the callback logic.

But all of those are implementation details and it is possible those details will change. You should not build your code with the assumption this code will run synchronously. Any addition of await inside `DoSomthingAsync` will make the code completely asynchronous without you noticing.

Also, `DoSomthingAsync` the way it is right now does not compile. You either remove the `async`, in which case it is clear that `DoSomthingAsync` is not asynchronous. Or you just have `return true;` , in which case the compiler should warn you that method does not contain any await and will complete synchronously.

Considering your question in comment:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync()
{
  statement2;
  await statement3; // << Diverges here
  statement4;
  return true;
}

// all code below this line is completely irrelevant 
// to whenever or where the code above diverges

public async Task MyMethod()
{
  statement1;
  await DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
  statement5;
}
```

Comment: "But all of those are implementation details and it is possible those details will change." Well, not quite. The behavior if the task has already completed is guaranteed by the C# spec (section 7.7.7.2 of the C# 5 spec for example).

Comment: Assume the statements inside `DoSomethingAsync` also introduce await calls however there is no `Task.Run(...)` or any other task creation mechanism in these await hierarchal calls at all, so are awaits going to create a task implicitly ever?

Comment: @muaz In which case the code will behave asynchronously. It will use whatever TaskScheduler that is Current at the moment.

Comment: @Euphoric the microsoft documentation of Async-Await  says the code will diverge once an await is met inside an Async method but it is not clear whether it will diverge only if a task is triggered inside the awaited method  or it will diverge anyway like in the example I made.

Comment: @muaz If `DoSomethingAsync` awaits some other task, then whether `DoSomethingAsync` is actually asynchronous depends on what the task it awaits does, just like `MyMethod`'s behavior is dependant on what `DoSomethingAsync` does.  If that other task that you `await` does work asynchronously , then `DoSomethingAsync` will be asynchronous, but if it's an already completed `Task`, then `DoSomethingAsync` will run synchronously.

Comment: @Servy so you say that await depends on what is waited so if we have many nested awaits but no task is created at all, then the code is synchronous and this would be a misuse of async-await mechanism

Comment: @muaz Lots of tasks are being created here in the code that you've shown.  Whether or not these operations are asynchronous is dependant on whether, at the lowest level, the `Task` being awaited *is not complete at the time that you `await` it*.  If it's already completed, the code runs synchronously, if it's not completed, the code runs asynchronously.  It would be misuse of `await` it performed *long running* synchronous work.  Doing very fast synchronous work, but returning `Tasks` for the purpose of polymorphism is not uncommon, and isn't misuse.

Comment: @Servy so conceptually await by itself will try to create a task (fast, slow or runs asynchronous I dont care) even though no explicit `Task.Run(...)` or any other approach of task creation is called inside the awaited method.

Comment: @muaz `await` doesn't create a `Task`.  Marking a method as `async` results in the method creating a new task and returning that new task.  The behavior of that `Task` is dependant on the body of the method, including when that returned task completes.